# No funciona WiFi

Tags: wifi

I installed the system on Mac Pro, everything works fine except that the wireless card is not recognized. I tried the `sudo pantheon-files` command and it doesn't work, how can I fix it?

The controller is Broadcom BCM 4360 (re v.03)

Thank you,

---

Original (Spanish):

Instalé el sistema en Mac Pro funciona todo bien excepto que no recose la placa de wifi. Probé con el comando sudo pantheon-files y no funciona, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar? El contralor es Broadcom BCM 4360 (re v.03) Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez:

1. Conecta a internet por cable ethernet o por bluetooth
2. En AppCenter, instala bcmwl-kernel-source
3. Reinicia la computadora

Tengo Mac Pro con otro contralor BCM 43xx y esto funciono para mi.